# Normalize variable per group

Tags: r

Given I have some data, that is grouped twice (once by `What` and once by `Who`):

```
data <-read.table(header = TRUE, text="What  Who    Time
aaa Alice   17
aaa Bob 20
aaa Carol   16
bbb Alice   23
bbb Bob 22
bbb Carol   19
ccc Alice   19
ccc Bob 19
ccc Carol   23
")
```

How can I normalize one variable (`Time` here) within a group (eg, `what`) to one of the other group members (eg `Alice` of `Who`)?

```
  What   Who Time               What   Who Time                What   Who  Time
1  aaa Alice   17             1  aaa Alice   17/17           1  aaa Alice     1
2  aaa   Bob   20             2  aaa   Bob   20/17           2  aaa   Bob 1.176
3  aaa Carol   16       \     3  aaa Carol   16/17      \    3  aaa Carol 0.941
4  bbb Alice   23    ----\    4  bbb Alice   23/23   ----\   4  bbb Alice     1
5  bbb   Bob   22    ----/    5  bbb   Bob   22/23   ----/   5  bbb   Bob 0.957
6  bbb Carol   19       /     6  bbb Carol   19/23      /    6  bbb Carol 0.826
7  ccc Alice   19             7  ccc Alice   19/19           7  ccc Alice     1
8  ccc   Bob   19             8  ccc   Bob   19/19           8  ccc   Bob     1
9  ccc Carol   23             9  ccc Carol   23/19           9  ccc Carol 1.211
```

**Edit:** Based on the answer by @amit, I came up with the following function

```
normalizeTo <- function(df, supergroup, group, val, var, vars=c(var)) {
  data <- df
  indexes <- which(df[[group]] == val)
  norm.factor <- (df[[var]])[indexes]
  names(norm.factor) <- (df[[supergroup]])[indexes]
  for (normvar in vars) {
    data[[paste0(normvar,".norm")]] <- df[[normvar]]/norm.factor[ df[[supergroup]] ]
  }
  data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would work:

```
a = which(data$Who=="Alice")
norm.factor = data$Time[a]
names(norm.factor) = data$What[a]
data$norm.time = data$Time/norm.factor[data$What]
```

Comment: So the clue here is the `norm.factor[data$What]` part. But why?

Comment: norm.factor gives the normalizing factor for each group (e.g. it is a vector of length 3 in your example), indexed by group name. now for each row in your data you want to know what is its normalizing factor. well, that's simple. take its group name (which is in data$What) and use it as an index to the norm.factor vector.
does it answer your question?

Comment: Hmm, I seem to get NAs for the normalized values towards the end of my _actual_ data, which does happen with these values here. Any Idea?

Comment: OK, I had excess levels in my `What` factor, that produced `NA`s. Neverming